# Native Ad Express Admob only shows if I specify the width and height to a certain dp

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, native-ads

I'm having a problem with my Native Ad. The ad will appear if I specify the ad to be 320x80. But I need the width to be different for different devices so I am trying this:

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312"
        ads:adSize="FULLWIDTHx80"></com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

This doesn't work and when I use wrap_content it just doesn't show the AD.

So I've tried this :

```
 // find out the width of the device in dp
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float deviceWidthInDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        int adWidth = (int)(deviceWidthInDp);

        adView = new NativeExpressAdView(context);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312");
        adView.setAdSize(new AdSize(adWidth, 80));
```

This also does not display the Ad.

Logcat is showing:

Not enough space to load AD needs to be 360x80dp but only has 319x80dp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove padding which was brought in from the generated Tabbed Activity:

For each tab.xml i.e tab1.xml tab2.xml:

```
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

This allowed more width so the Ad would appear. Hope it helps someone